# Deleting Files in Subfolder and delete empty Folders

Tags: vb.net, plugins

I have to write a PlugIn (in VB.NET) that deletes files after a set amount of days. I've been using this Code to "delete" all files older then `DataAge`:

For testing purposes I use `Log(file.Name)` instead of `file.Delete()`.

```
Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(.PluginXML.DeleteDirectory)  //.PluginXML.DeleteDirectory = FilePath

    For Each file As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles()
        If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > .PluginXML.DataAge Then Log(file.Name)  //.PluginXML.DataAge = FileAge

    Next
```

How do I check for old files/empty folders in Subfolders from `.PluginXML.DeleteDirectory`?
I tried something like this, but it would delete the folders, instead of old files.

```
    For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In directory.GetDirectories()
        If (Now - folder.CreationTime).Days > .PluginXML.DataAge Then Log(folder.FullName)
    Next
```

Comment: It's called recursion. There are countless examples of a recursive file search on the web already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the [overload of `GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.6#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) (or even better*, [`EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.6#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)) that accepts a  [`SearchOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netframework-4.6) with which you can specify that it recurses all directories. For example:

```
For Each file As FileInfo In directory.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > .PluginXML.DataAge Then Log(file.Name)
Next
```

The alternative is to create a recursive function that walks the directory tree using [`EnumerateDirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories?view=netframework-4.6#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_EnumerateDirectories):

```
Public Sub ProcessDirectory(directory as DirectoryInfo, dataAge as Integer) 
    For Each file As FileInfo In directory.EnumerateFiles()
        If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > dataAge Then Log(file.Name)
    Next
    For Each subDir as DirectoryInfo In directory.EnumerateDirectories()
       ProcessDirectory(subDir, dataAge) 
    Next
End Sub
```

And then call the method using your base/root path

```
Dim rootDir As New DirectoryInfo(.PluginXML.DeleteDirectory)
ProcessDirectory(rootDir, .PluginXML.DataAge)
```

Though note that you will probably need to add error handling for when a directory is inaccessible, such as when an `UnauthorizedAccessException` or `SecurityException` is thrown.

* `GetFiles` loads all files into memory at once whereas `EnumerateFiles` returns an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` that streams the results. This has benefits if you are dealing with directories that contain lots of files, especially if using the `AllDirectories` option.